# Binding a nested list of objects to a listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have three classes which goes like this .. a client can receive multiple orders each order has multiple items and each item has multiple properties , and i want two show this in a listview .. so i found that having two listviews on android will cause an error when scrolling and the app will crash ..
so my question is what is the best way to bind the data and loop to show the nested list of orders with items and items properties in the xaml page ?

The viewModel

```
 public class PageViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomerOrders> _requestedItems;

    public ObservableCollection<CustomerOrders> RequestedItems
    {
        get => _requestedItems;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _requestedItems)) return;
            _requestedItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand GetRequestedItems
    {

        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                IsLoading = true;
                var accesstoken = Settings.AccessToken;
                RequestedItems = await _apiServices.GetCustomerDownloadOrdersAsync(accesstoken);


            });
        }
    }

}

 public class CustomerOrders
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string RequestUserName { get; set; }

    public List<DownloadOrderItem> RequestedItemInfo { get; set; }

}


  public class DownloadOrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I think the answer would be to find another way to display this. Maybe more of a drill down view. So, show the first list in the first screen, then show the second list based on the selection of the first list.

Comment: I was hoping that there is a way without the need to get the user moving to another screen .